# Select records with dates which are more than 6 months apart in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working one a dataset which looks like the table below

[image]

I am trying to fetch those dates which are more than 6 months apart starting in chronological order.

If `2019-03-04` is `i`, I want to loop over subsequents dates until I find the most recent one which is more than 6 months apart. This date, `2019-12-05` (from the table above) will then become the new `i` and I need to traverse the rest of the following dates to find the next one which is more than 6 months apart. This is to be done to find a set of dates for every `Id`.

In order to do that, I wrote the python snippet which is attached below.

```
df = Dataframe_to_be_traversed_filtered_on_1_user
x = df['Date'].tolist()
i=0
xx = [] //list_to_append_selected_dates
xx.append(x[0])
for j in range(i+1,len(x)):
  d1 = datetime.strptime(x[i],'%Y-%m-%d')
  d2 = datetime.strptime(x[j],'%Y-%m-%d')
  if((d2.year - d1.year) * 12 + (d2.month  - d1.month) >= 6 ):
    xx.append(x[j])
  else:
    continue 
  i=j
```

Can someone please help me to convert it to PySpark?

Edit: Edge case scenario

```
Id  Date    ToKeep
A   2019-03-04  1
A   2019-08-01  0
A   2019-12-05  1
A   2020-04-15  0
A   2020-07-12  1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am new to pyspark and don't know how to write loops, I was able to create a list to traverse using 
`df.select("Date").orderBy("Date").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()`
but not sure how to proceed.

Comment: if you have dates as string `year-mont-day` then you can compare strings like `"2019-03-04" < "2019-12-05"` and then you could filter without looping but `df['Date'] > "2019-12-05"` (where `"2019-12-05"` is `your date + 6 month`) and use ` `min()` to get exepected value.

Comment: use the lag function in spark with datediff to find the difference in dates. Partition over ID column and ordered on Dates column

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. I have added an edge case scenario in the question which I believe your solution might not be capturing. Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this works for you.

Partitioned By ID with lag function.

```
 from pyspark.sql import functions as func
 from pyspark.sql import Window
df_date = df.withColumn('prev_date',
                        func.lag(df['Date'])
                                 .over(Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("Date")))
```

[image]

Calculated months difference

```
df_months = df_date.withColumn("monthDiff", func.months_between(df_date["Date"],df_date["prev_date"]))
```

[image]

Added ToKeep column

When null or greater than 6 result will be 1 otherwise 0

```
df_final = df_months.withColumn("ToKeep",func.when(df_months.monthDiff.isNull(),1 ).when(df_months.monthDiff>6,1).otherwise(0))
```

[image]

Make sure Date column inferred as Date. If not, use to_date(df.Date, 'yyyy-MM-dd').

Comment: Hello Srinivasu, Thank you for a prompt response. I believe there is an edge case where your logic might not work. I have attached the edge case scenario in the question.. Please let me know your thoughts.